# borders are not visible in ie7

Tags: css

i want a border on bottom of a td.i got that using border:dotted 1px black;.but it is not visible in ie7.the td height is 10px.if i use &nbsp it is visible in ie7.but i dont need that much height.can anyone help me? Here My Code

```
<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head>
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8" />
<title>Untitled Document</title>
<style type="text/css">
<!--
.border {
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
    border-bottom-style: dotted;
    border-bottom-color: #0099FF;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
}
body {
    margin-left: 0px;
    margin-top: 0px;
    margin-right: 0px;
    margin-bottom: 0px;
}
-->
</style>
</head>

<body>
<table width="80%" border="0" align="center" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0">
  <tr>
    <td height="10" class="border"  ></td>
    <td height="10" class="border" ></td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: having empty table cells sounds to me like you are using tables for layout - which isn't such a good idea. if i'm right: can't you do your layout in another way? - and if i'm wrong: could you please post some code (the table you are talking about and your css)?

Answer (score 0):

```
table {
 border-collapse: collapse;
}
```

Comment: i don't think this is what S.Rangaraj is asking for - this would help if there are ugly double-bprders between the cells, but there is nothing...